# Tex error: TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [.6=200000]

Tags: compiling, tex-core, capacity

While a compilation of my file `thesis.tex`, my computer is stopped and it restarts. Then when I reopen the file, no contain is viewed (although the file size is always 295 kB !), and any compilation is processed with error:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (MiKTeX 20.11) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2020.11.16)  16 NOV 2020 12:37
entering extended mode
**./thesis.tex
(thesis.tex
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [.6=200000].
l.1 
> 
> If you really absolutely need more capacity,
you can ask a wizard to enlarge me.
> 
> Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 6 strings out of 479799,
 144 string characters out of 2870197,
 264509 words of memory out of 12000000,
 17099 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000,
 535088 words of font info for 29 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000,
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191,
 0i,0n,0p,1b,6s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s,
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Thank for your recommendation !

Comment: does it really say `.6` ? that is very weird

Comment: Good thing that a `.tex` file is just a text file, so it can not be corrupted in subtle ways. I have no idea about the error. Try to delete everything (EXCEPT your sources .tex files) and compile again. -or try moving the sources to another working system.

Comment: Thanks for comments and editing. 

I follows some guide to enlarge the memory. 
But a new error occurs: 

"! Text line contains an invalid character.
l.3 
A funny symbol that I can't read has just been input.
Continue, and I'll forget that it ever happened."

So, I guess that my issue concerns an automatic adding of strange characters into my file. But the problem is that the file's content can't be viewed. I don't know how to recover the file.

Comment: TeX shouldn't say “.6=200000”; so unfortunately it appears that something is seriously corrupted on your system. Hope you have backups!